# How can i automatic create file tex from template?

Tags: templates

i have group of template: templateA_1.tex, templateA_2.tex, templateA_3.tex, templateB_1.tex,templateB_2.tex, templateB_3.tex.

How can i automatic create 2 file tex from templateA_1.tex & templateB_1.tex and change variableA inside?

i definite variableA and source to copy in all.tex:

```
\def\ArrayName{{"CopyA","CopyB"}}
Copy templateA_1
Copy templateB_1
```

Example code of template A_1.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Template A1
Hello world \variableA
 \end{document}
```

A copy of TemplateA_1:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \begin{document}
    Template A1
    Hello world \CopyA
   \end{document}
```

and the name of created file = CopyA.tex.

Can use \write18? If yes, how use it?
Please help

Thanks

Comment: This sounds more like something you'd do with a shell script and sed rather than a TeX question...

Comment: Sounds like a task for `sed` and `printf` and (maybe) `pandoc`, not directly LaTeX. Voting to close.

Comment: You could also use LuaTeX and something like YAML. Though that might be overkill.

Comment: tex is a macro expansion language so it's not clear you need any template at all, what do you need other than `\newcommand\variableA{text for copyA}` at the start of the file (or on the commandline for processing the file?)

Comment: @close-voters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, **but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.**

Comment: @Mensch your comment seems out of place there are no downvotes on this question

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're wanting to do.  You mention 8 different tex files, but only give brief examples of 3.  In addition to some `\newcommand`s, `\input` may also be useful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But there are close-votes. Therefore my added `@close-voters:` and the part in comment printed bold ;-) And hopefully the contained text about down-voting stops downvoting before it starts ...

Comment: i read topic that shell embeded in latex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex but i dont know how use in my case. thanks

Comment: @Mensch better to write a comment than use a standard boiler-plate three quarters of which doesn't apply.

Comment: @latexforti if yoy want to edit the file to make multiple modified file better to use perl or some other scripting language but it isn't at all clear why you need to do that as opposed to just defining `\variableA` as a tex macro, why do you need a "template" at all. It is very hard to understand your examples as both of the latex documents shown will give undefined command errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, then one is clear: we think different. That could happen, is human and democratic. I stay with my way thinking, you can stay with yours. No problem for me ...